# Selected Row of a Datagrid, I want to show a field in textbox

Tags: c#

The data grid has

Employer name | location | number

When I select the first row, I need that the employer name must be showed in a lbl.

Comment: grdemployers.selectedRow["Employer_name"]

Answer (score 0):

you can use row databound event .to get the selected row employee name . the selected row event is fired so it can be handle in row data bound event

Answer (score 0):

Work with the source and get the row and then work from the result to get the value you need, you can do this on the on cell click

```
   private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

       //get the result
       var result = (CastFromSource)this.dgvReport.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;


    }
```